# Java create JSONObject with empty value as JSONObject

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to create an JSONObject with a specific key and empty value. But the value should be a JSONObject and not a JSONArray.

I already tried it with `localJson.append(key, JSONObject.NULL);` or `localJson.append(key, new JSONObject());`.
Each time the value is a JSONArray with the `value[0] = null` or just `[{}]`

Is there any way to make it a JSONObject?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] rather than just describing what you've tried.

Comment: Also you should specify which library you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject*:

Use `public JSONObject put(String key, Object value)`instead of `append` method.

Your code isn't working because method `JSONObject append(String key, Object value)` is defined as follows:

```java
public JSONObject append(String key, Object value) throws JSONException {
    testValidity(value);
    Object o = opt(key);
    if (o == null) {
        put(key, new JSONArray().put(value));
    } else if (!(o instanceof JSONArray)){
        throw new JSONException("JSONObject[" + key + "] is not a JSONArray.");
    } else {
        put(key, new JSONArray().put(o).put(value));
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: wow .. thank you ... I hate myself for that. I had this part open and read eatch time JSONObject instead of JSONArray >.>